# Как найти последний вложеный элемент у одного из вложеных массивов

Tags: php

Как найти последний вложенный элемент двумерного массива?

```
<?php
$arr = array(

    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "name"  => array(1,2,333), // получить 333
    100   => -100

);
```

Comment: А почему 1? Судя по вопросу 333 надо.

Comment: Ну и причем тут **последний** элемент массива?!

Comment: Для начала, определитесь с тем, что вам нужно, а уже потом задавайте вопросы. Правка вопроса раз в пять секунд не делает вам чести!

Comment: @DmitriySimushev это конечный вариант

Comment: @jo_ho13121212, уверены? А почему текст и заголовок вопроса не соответствуют коду?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev уверен,ну а как бы вы переформулировали?

Comment: @jo_ho13121212, кто задает вопрос? вы или я? Лично я не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду под "последним вложенным" элементом

Comment: @jo_ho13121212, вы уже третий раз меняете условия вопроса, есть риск, что вас просто заминусуют и тогда вопрос никто не увидит.

Answer (score 2):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
    "name"  => array(1,2,333),
    100   => -100
);
foreach($arr as $el) {
  if(is_array($el)) {
    echo end($el);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Думаю стоит дождаться окончательной формализации задачи. А то сейчас это игра в "угадайку" (ну или телепатию)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev угу

Comment: описал максимально точно

Comment: @jo_ho13121212, ну вот на ваше "максимально точно" вам и дали четкий ответ. Если он вам не подходит, то проблема тут явно не в ответе ;-)